# Rails 2.3.9 and SendGrid, Connection refused - connect(2) on localhost

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, actionmailer, sendgrid

I've looked through Google and StackOverflow and can't figure this out.

I've got a Rails 2.3.9 app using Ruby 1.8.7, trying to send email through SMTP like so:

```
ActionMailer::Base.delivery_method = :smtp
ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings = {
  :address => "smtp.sendgrid.net",
  :port => '25',
  :domain => "************.com",
  :authentication => :plain,
  :user_name => "***********",
  :password => "**********"
}
```

My app backtrace looks like this:

```
/Users/jared/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p334/lib/ruby/1.8/net/smtp.rb:551:in `initialize'
/Users/jared/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p334/lib/ruby/1.8/net/smtp.rb:551:in `open'
/Users/jared/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p334/lib/ruby/1.8/net/smtp.rb:551:in `do_start'
/Users/jared/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p334/lib/ruby/1.8/timeout.rb:67:in `timeout'
/Users/jared/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p334/lib/ruby/1.8/timeout.rb:101:in `timeout'
/Users/jared/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p334/lib/ruby/1.8/net/smtp.rb:551:in `do_start'
/Users/jared/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p334/lib/ruby/1.8/net/smtp.rb:525:in `start'
/Users/jared/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p334/gems/actionmailer-2.3.9/lib/action_mailer/base.rb:682:in `perform_delivery_smtp'
/Users/jared/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p334/gems/actionmailer-2.3.9/lib/action_mailer/base.rb:523:in `__send__'
/Users/jared/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p334/gems/actionmailer-2.3.9/lib/action_mailer/base.rb:523:in `deliver!'
/Users/jared/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p334/gems/actionmailer-2.3.9/lib/action_mailer/base.rb:429:in `deliver'
/Users/jared/rails/********/app/models/user.rb:160:in `send_welcome_email'
/Users/jared/rails/*********/app/controllers/users_controller.rb:35:in `create'
```

Comment: Can you `telnet smtp.sendgrid.net 25`? Are you running a network filter such as Little Snitch and are blocking outgoing connections? Some ISPs also block outgoing port 25, requiring you to connect to their SMTP server (ostensibly to make it harder for their users send spam).

Comment: No I can't. Which verifies the solution I came up with below.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I figured it out.  My ISP was blocking port 25, so I had to change my configuration:

```
ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings = {
  :address => "smtp.sendgrid.net",
  :port => '587',
  :domain => "**********.com",
  :authentication => :plain,
  :user_name => "************",
  :password => "*********",
  :enable_starttls_auto => true
}
```