# How to skip email confirmation for users who uses Devise rpx conecteable

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, devise, ruby-on-rails-3.1, rpxnow

I am working on a mini project and i dont know how to skip email confirmation for users who uses devise_rpx_connectable_to sign in, Every time i try to sign in using this services it sends email confirmation to those users.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can always override this method in User class:

```
def confirmation_required?
      !confirmed?
end
```

for example you can check there if `rpx_identifier.blank?`

try this code:

```
def confirmation_required?
      !confirmed? and rpx_identifier.blank?
end
```

Comment: do you mean something like this `  def confirmation_required?
      !confirmed? if rpx_identifier.blank?
  end`

Comment: i get the error when signing up a new user without the devise rpx `Connection refused - connect(2)`

Comment: users signing in without rpx should be sent a confirmation

Comment: your new error indicates that your email can not go from your machine. Please look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5223858/rails-2-3-9-and-sendgrid-connection-refused-connect2-on-localhost

Comment: super :) have a nice day Uchenna